# Is the module of kahler differentials noetherian?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

The question is in the title. Let $X$ be an algebraic or analytic set. i want to know if every submodule of the  $\mathcal{O}_X$-module of the kahler differentials of a fixed degree  is finitely generated ?

Comment: What is, for you, "an algebraic or analytic set"?

Comment: I mean by  analytic or algebraic sets zeros of polynomial or holomorphic functions in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: For any algebraic variety $X$, the sheaf $\Omega ^1_X$ is coherent, hence any sub-$\mathscr{O}_X$-module is of finite type. Same in the analytic set-up, using the correct definition of  $\Omega ^1_X$.

Comment: I don't understand. I agree that a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ of $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-module is in particular finitely generated because of the exact sequence $ \mathcal{O}_{X}(U)^s \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X}(U)^t \rightarrow \mathcal{F}_{X}(U) \rightarrow 0$ ( for some open set $U$) implies in particular $\mathcal{O}_{X}(U)^t \rightarrow \mathcal{F}_{X}(U)$ is surjective. But how do you conclude something for a submodule of $\mathcal{F}_{X}(U)$?

Comment: I think i get it. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is coherent there exists a surjective morphism  $h:\mathcal{O}_{X}(U)^t \rightarrow \mathcal{F}_{X}(U)$ for some $t \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $M$ be a submodule of $\mathcal{F}_{X}(U)$ then $h^{-1}(M)$ is a submodule of $\mathcal{O}_{X}(U)^t$ which is finitely generated. It implies that the map $h_{|h^{-1}(M)}: h^{-1}(M) \longrightarrow M$  is a surjective morphism of module. Since $\mathcal{O}_{X}(U)^t$ is noeherian it implies that $h^{-1}(M)$ is  finitely generated hence $M$ is finitely generated. i'm i missing something ?